# How to show row number in Access query like ROW_NUMBER in SQL

Tags: ms-access-2007, row-number

I have a table in Microsoft Access, and I want to show row number in a column using a select query in Access just like using `ROW_NUMBER()` function in SQL Server.

In SQL Server, I can using this query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tblUser.UserID) AS NoRow, * 
FROM tblUser
```

I use same query in access, but I get error.

Can you help me?

Comment: Here are a few [**Ways To Do Sequential Numbering in Access**](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2015/07/28/ways-to-do-sequential-numbering-in-access/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
Select A.*, (select count(*) from Table1 where A.ID>=ID) as RowNo
from Table1 as A
order by A.ID
```

Comment: My column data type any type and no number & no unique.Can I resolve row_index?

Comment: It works, but with large table with about 30K records and mdb file size 60 MB it failed to complete.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this with MS Access is with a subquery but it does not have anything like the same functionality:

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.AText, 
       (SELECT Count(ID) 
        FROM table1 b WHERE b.ID <= a.ID 
        AND b.AText Like "*a*") AS RowNo
FROM Table1 AS a
WHERE a.AText Like "*a*"
ORDER BY a.ID;
```

Comment: I don't understand with where condition (AND b.AText Like "*a*") and (a.AText Like "*a*")

Comment: It's just to indicate that whatever WHERE statements you'll need in your outer query must be copied to the inner one as well.

Answer (score 1):

by VB function:

```
Dim m_RowNr(3) as Variant
'
Function RowNr(ByVal strQName As String, ByVal vUniqValue) As Long
' m_RowNr(3)
' 0 - Nr
' 1 - Query Name
' 2 - last date_time
' 3 - UniqValue

If Not m_RowNr(1) = strQName Then
  m_RowNr(0) = 1
  m_RowNr(1) = strQName
ElseIf DateDiff("s", m_RowNr(2), Now) > 9 Then
  m_RowNr(0) = 1
ElseIf Not m_RowNr(3) = vUniqValue Then
  m_RowNr(0) = m_RowNr(0) + 1
End If

m_RowNr(2) = Now
m_RowNr(3) = vUniqValue
RowNr = m_RowNr(0)

End Function
```

Usage(without sorting option):

```
SELECT RowNr('title_of_query_or_any_unique_text',A.id) as Nr,A.*
From table A
Order By A.id
```

if sorting required or multiple tables join then create intermediate table:

```
 SELECT RowNr('title_of_query_or_any_unique_text',A.id) as Nr,A.*
 INTO table_with_Nr
 From table A
 Order By A.id
```