# Access: Count the First Instance of Each Unique Value in a Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to return a 1 for the first instance of each unique value in a column, and return a 0 for each repeating value after the first unique instance.

In Excel I've used the below formula but on a larger sheet it becomes unstable.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,1,0)

ID    Unique
ABC1       1
ABC1       0
ABC1       0
ABC2       1
ABC3       1
ABC3       0
ABC4       1
```

Comment: MS Access works with unordered datasets, therefore you'll first need to define a sort order so that you can unambiguously define what constitutes the "first instance". Does your table have an incrementing primary key by which it could be sorted, for example?

Comment: Yes I could sort by primary key

Comment: Does your table have `ID` and a separate primary key column?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT IDPK, ID, DCount("*","TableName","ID='" & [ID] & "' AND IDPK<" & [IDPK])+1 AS U, 
       IIf([U]=1,1,0) AS [Unique]
FROM TableName
ORDER BY IDPK;
```

Be aware that domain aggregate functions can cause slow performance in large datasets. However, same can be said of nested subquery to accomplish same result. More info [How to show row number in Access query like ROW_NUMBER in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683226/how-to-show-row-number-in-access-query-like-row-number-in-sql). Report option using textbox RunningSum property might be fastest performer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a numerical primary key `pk`, then the following should yield the desired result:

```
select t.pk, t.id, -not exists (select 1 from Table1 u where u.id=t.id and u.pk<t.pk)
from Table1 t
order by t.pk
```

Change both occurrences of `Table1` to the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the table to itself on the grouping column `ID`, but only where the primary key on the joined column is *greater than* the primary key of the main row. Then use fact that there won't be a joined column for the first (lowest primary_key) instance of a distinct `ID` value to generate either `1` or `0` accordingly:

```
select
    a.ID,
    if(b.ID is null, 1, 0) as is_unique
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.ID = a.ID
  and b.primary_key > a.primary_key
order by a.primary_key
```