# Auto ID returned with the recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access

Does exist a way in MS-ACCESS SQL to have an auto ID (a column with incrementing integer) returned with a recordset?

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT (ID)?, H.Code_BB, H.Name_BB, B.group, B.subgroup, H.DataDiEstrazione " & _
        "FROM " & _
        "dbHoldings AS H " & _
        "INNER JOIN dbBuildingBlockList AS B " & _
        "ON H.Code_BB=B.Code_BB " & _
        "ORDER BY B.group, B.subgroup, H.Code_BB  ;"
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What does your schema look like? What's not working in the SQL you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think row number is what you are looking for. Row number will be unique for each rows.
Example:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
 ORDER BY first_name
 ) row_num,
 first_name, 
 last_name, 
 city
FROM 
 sales.customers;
```

For MS Acess you can use

```
Select A.*, (select count(*) from Table1 where A.ID>=ID) as RowNo
from Table1 as A
order by A.ID
```

Refer answer: [How to get row number in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683226/how-to-show-row-number-in-access-query-like-row-number-in-sql)