# C# SQL "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CTPoints ASC)"

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I'm getting a syntax error but I do not know where it is. I'm trying to find the nth row in a table in SQL.

I am using C# with OleDb as the connection.

```
SELECT 
    TName, CTPoints 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CTPoints ASC) AS RowNumber, 
         *
     FROM 
         TeamChampionship) AS foo 
WHERE 
    RowNumber = 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That error message seems like you are using Access? That doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/14683226/73226 - though seems you should just use `top 1` as you don't need the numbering

Comment: You're not partitioning your rows so you just need an *order by* criteria here.

Comment: Oof, I think you've reached the point where a database upgrade is in order..